# Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 error Named Pipes Provider Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic, load, adodb

We are retrieving some Microsoft SQL Server records from a classic ASP page.  If the number of records sometimes exceeds 200 records, it might throw the following error:

Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 error '80004005'

Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [1326].

/review/blabblahblah.asp, line 169

Moreover, it really fails to make sense that the error is throw at a line where "end if" for an if statement:

```
dim strSQLPref, rsPref, cntReviewerPrefs
set rsPref = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSQLPref = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS blabhlah " & _
             "FROM blabhlah " & _
             "WHERE blabhlah = " & blabhlah & " " & _
             "AND blabhlah = " & FixID(blabhlah ) & " "
        if DisplayType = "Preferences" then
             strSQLPref = strSQLPref & "AND blabhlah = " & fixTextForDB(blabhlah ) & " "
         else
             strSQLPref = strSQLPref & "AND blabhlah = 'on' "
          end if
```

Please provide suggestions. Does it have to do something with amount of records from the Microsoft SQL Server Database?

Comment: It would probably be more helpful if you included the code relevant to the connection setup and the execution of your query so we might be able to see if there is anything in that. Two items of curiosity in what I *do* see -- not explanations for the issue, but mere curiosity:

(1) Any particular reason you're using Named Pipes instead of TCP?
(2) For what it's worth, I'd suggest parameterized stored procedures instead of a maze of SQL string construction, but that's not the issue itself.

Comment: Please tell me how I can specify within VBScript code  the connectivity to Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Database using TCP

Comment: Again, it was more just a question -- without seeing the larger scope of your code that includes your connection setup and your query execution, you've not given us anything that would help solve what appears to be a technical/infrastruction/network-related issue, not a logic problem. That said, here's a link to how you can set up a connection string to connect via TCP explicitly: http://www.connectionstrings.com/define-sql-server-network-protocol/